# Magento 2 Customer Account Navigation Multiple tabs Not working

Tags: magento2, customer-account

I created two Tabs in customer account Navigation, 1st tab is working 2nd tab is not working

**`customer_account.xml`**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-module-index-index">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">module/index/index</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true"> Tab Name</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-module-index-history">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">module/index/history</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true"> Tab Name 1</argument>
                </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
    </body>
 </page>
```

**`layout.xml`**

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <referenceContainer name="content">
                <block class="Package\Module\Block\Index\Index" name="module_index_index" template="Module_Namespace::module_index_index.phtml"></block>
            </referenceContainer>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
             <referenceContainer name="content">
                <block class="Package\Module\Block\Index\History" name="module_index_history" template="Module_Namespace::module_index_history.phtml"></block>
            </referenceContainer>
        </referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First in `customer_account.xml` instead of two `<referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">` you have to merge them like below

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-module-index-index">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">module/index/index</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true"> Tab Name</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-module-index-history">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">module/index/history</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true"> Tab Name 1</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
 </page>
```

Then instead of a single `layout.xml` you have to create two separate layout files to call your templates

1. `module_index_index.xml`
2. `module_index_history.xml`

With below code

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/> 
    <body>           
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Package\Module\Block\Index\Index" name="module_index_index" template="Module_Namespace::module_index_index.phtml"></block> 
        </referenceContainer> 
    </body> 
</page>
```

For second layout file change your block name and template path

Comment: How to active that tab

Comment: isn't it showing active by default for  link?

Comment: No it's not showing

Comment: it should work be default, though you can try this -https://gist.github.com/herveguetin/11374425#gistcomment-1714033

Answer (score 2):

Now try this

> customer_account.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-module-index-index">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">module/index/index</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tab Name</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-module-index-history">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">module/index/history</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tab Name 1</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
 </page>
```

> module_index_history.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
         <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Package\Module\Block\Index\History" name="module_index_history" template="Module_Namespace::module_index_history.phtml"></block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Same output only both page content show only one page 2nd page empty

Comment: 2nd page phtml file add your code and call it.

Comment: Where i need to add

Comment: please check my updated code

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code in file `customer_account.xml` from

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-module-index-index">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">module/index/index</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true"> Tab Name</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-module-index-history">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">module/index/history</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true"> Tab Name 1</argument>
                </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
    </body>
 </page>
```

**To:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-module-index-index">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">module/index/index</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true"> Tab Name1</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-module-index-history">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">module/index/history</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true"> Tab Name2</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
         </referenceBlock>
    </body>
 </page>
```

Comment: After add this code tab itself not showing

Comment: Updated ans pls check. Have you run: bin/magento setup:di:compile?

Comment: Tab itself not showing